# Change title of page dynamically in page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I have an page (with snippet code and short code and manual php code) and it call a REST API and base Of response, I want **change tag title** of this page *(Not in database)*.and it was change every call.

i try do :

in snippet code:

```
$GLOBALS['MyTitle'] = $response-> title;
```

in function:

```
function change_title($title) {
 
        $variable = $GLOBALS['MyTitle'];
      
        if (!empty($variable)) 
        {
             $title = $variable;
        } 
    
    return $title;
}
add_filter('pre_get_document_title', 'change_title',500);
```

but it was empty every time because the function section run sooner then snippet code(Api Call).

WordPress has not any function for change title tag text? like `wp_set_title('my title')` to use without `add_filter`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33101/how-do-i-set-the-page-title-dynamically

Comment: @laraCoder no, I saw it later. most of them add a predefine text to title. and global variable not work for my end

Answer (score 1):

Changing title of the page dynamically by applying the filter the hook used for the filter is document_title_parts. Here is the official wordpress [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_parts/) link and below is the example. In this example i have used get method for API.

```
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', 'function_to_dynamic_title');
function function_to_dynamic_title( $title_parts_array ) {

        $request = wp_remote_get( 'https://dummyjson.com/products/1' );

        if( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
            return $data;
        }

        $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );

        $data = json_decode( $body );

        $title_parts_array['title'] = $data->title;
    
    return $title_parts_array;
}
```

Screenshot for your reference
[image]

Comment: thank you @j-shabu but I told in my question. i not want use $post I call an api and the param of it must show as title.

Comment: @foadabdollahi I have updated the answer please check it.

Comment: 'YOUR TEXT DYNAMIC #' is an static text :)

Comment: Can you send me the api url ?

Comment: the api is in local sever and has not public view but it is not difference use  mockapi.io and call it in an snippet and shortcut it in a page . then change page title base of api result

Comment: @j-shabu thank u so much. but I call api in snippet. with this solution I must call api twice

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress, we have an action to change the title programmatically.

```
add_filter('the_title','your_callback_function');
function your_callback_function($data)
{
  global $post;
  // add your condition according to page 
  return 'Desired Title'. $post->ID;
}
```

Comment: not work with my global parameter defined in snippet code(call external API)